# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher doesn't work

Tags: windows

I have Windows 10 Pro, build 10586.494 on HP ZBook G2. When I go to Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth and switch on Bluetooth, I can see nearby BLE devices (they are custom made BLE devices manufactured by my company).

I want to interact with my BLE devices in Universal Windows application (in Visual Studio 2015). I use this code (it is just a snippet of code)

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
//....
    watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };
    watcher.Received += WatcherOnReceived;
    watcher.Start();
//....
    private void WatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs btAdv)
    {
    }
```

When I run this application, WatcherOnReceived is never executed (although watcher.Start was executed). Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you declared the Bluetooth capability in the App manifest?

Comment: Yes, I checked Bluetooth checkbox in Capabilities tab in Package.appxmanifest

Answer (score 1):

If found a better workaround for this. (I'm using Win 10 1803.)

First, to recap the problem since the original question is not entirely clear about it:

- BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher works if BLE device is advertising before `watcher.Start()`
- BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher does not work if BLE device starts advertising after `watcher.Start()`
- If BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher is not working after `watcher.Start()`, it will begin working when Windows 10 Bluetooth Settings is opened or closed (i.e. the opening or closing of the settings window triggers BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher to start working)

So, the workaround I came up with is to keep starting and stopping a second BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher in the background to create the same sort of trigger that the Windows Bluetooth Settings window provides.

For example, using a WinForms timer:

```
... 
var timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
...

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
  watcher.Received += (s, a) => { };
  watcher.Start();
  Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => watcher.Stop());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to keep Bluetooth switched on in Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth in order to receive advertisements in my app.

Comment: It seems to be some problems when the advertisement watcher is started, even though the callback is set up correctly (so you get the advertisements). I'd suggest you ask in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=wdk since there are Microsoft people there giving support.

Comment: What do you mean you have to keep Bluetooth switched on in settings? Do you mean the settings window has to stay open or that you just have to have the toggle on?